# How do I run my syncronus search function wihout blocking my flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I am building a flutter application which searches a low level communication bus for devices and displays them in a table. Communication over the low level bus is slow, default speed is 4800 bits/s.

I want to run my search in the background so that the application is not halted for 10+ seconds every time the user performs a search. I also want to add the results to the table as the search function finds them (using the `onFound` argument to `search`).

```
SearchBar(
  onSearch: (selection, parametersToDisplay) {
    clearSearchResults();
    communcationBus.search(selection, parametersToDisplay, onFound: (device) {addToSearchResults(device)})
  },
  onUpdateSearch: (display) {}, // TODO
  )
```

Comment: Have a look at isolates in Flutter / Dart, there are some packages as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Isolates.

For a short conceptual intro, take a look at [this Medium post by a Dart documentation writer](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart-asynchronous-programming-isolates-and-event-loops-bffc3e296a6a).

The `FlutterIsolate` package ([pub link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate)) can help you to abstract out some of the complicated things.

You can use it to `spawn` a new isolate, which performs your slow operations. You can then store it in your app or use the `SendPort`/`ReceivePort` to send the result data to your main isolate.